# Array functor exercise

Tags: arrays, scala, manifest, scalaz

I'm having a look at [20 Intermediate Scala Exercises](http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/20-intermediate-scala-exercises/) and am having some difficulty with exercise 4. Unfortunately I can't find any solutions posted anywhere and I'm wondering if it's actually solvable.

`Fluffy` is clearly a thinly disguised `Functor` and `furry` is `fmap`.

```
trait Fluffy[F[_]] {
  def furry[A, B](f: A => B, fa: F[A]): F[B]
}

object Fluffy {
  // Exercise 1
  // Relative Difficulty: 1
  def ListFluffy: Fluffy[List] = new Fluffy[List] {
    def furry[A, B](f: A => B, fa: List[A]): List[B] = fa map f
         // am assuming this is the right idea...
  }

  // Exercise 4
  // Relative Difficulty: 1
  def ArrayFluffy: Fluffy[Array] = new Fluffy[Array] {
    def furry[A, B](f: A => B, fa: Array[A]): Array[B] = ???
  }
```

The problem is that I can't create an `Array[B]` without a context bound `B: ClassManifest`, but if I add one it breaks the contract with the `Fluffy` trait.

Since these questions are from 2008, presumbably before the days of `Manifest`, is the only option in Scala 2.9 to ignore the exercises involving arrays, or is there some other way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Use scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/4344) it's not solvable since scala 2.8